# Javascript expression in parentheses

Tags: javascript

```
var x = (1,2,3);
alert(x);
```

This expression evaluates to 3.

How is this expression **`(1,2,3)`** called? Why does it return 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javascript has a [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) [operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14), like C does.  It evaluates each of the expressions, then returns the last one.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen this in Javascript before.  But in a number of other C'ish languages, it basically evaluates each of the expressions in the parentheses and returns the value of the last one.