# multer file is undefined in express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

Here is my axios post request.

```js
await axios
      .post(
        status === "register"
          ? "api/v1/publicUsers/register"
          : "api/v1/publicUsers/login",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          onUploadProgress: (data) => {
            setProgress(Math.round((100 * data.loaded) / data.total));
            console.log(progress);
          },

          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
```

Here is the backend service layer for getting the file uploads and other form data.

```js
module.exports.publicUsersService =
  (upload.any(),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
    }
    )
```

That `upload` is coming from the `multerInstance` file which contains:

```js
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "../public/uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
module.exports = upload;
```

Form snippet:

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <input
              onChange={handleEmail}
              type="email"
              className="border-black border-2 mt-5 w-72 p-3"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
            <br />
            <input
              onChange={handlePass}
              type="password"
              className="border-black border-2 mt-5 w-72 p-3"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
            />
            <br />
            {status === "register" && (
              <input
                onChange={handleFile}
                type="file"
                className="border-black border-2 mt-5 w-72 p-3"
                required={true}
                name="file"
                id="file"
              />
            )}
            <br />
            <div className="button flex justify-center bg-blue-600 mt-5 p-3">
              {status === "login" ? (
                <button className="">Login</button>
              ) : (
                <button className="">Register</button>
              )}
            </div>
          </form>
```

Now when I am submitting my form i am not getting any data in my `req.file` and `req.body`.
They are undefined.

Comment: Can you add more code? what is handleFile doing?

Comment: @Fischbrot i am getting the files as well as the formData on frontend. but they are just undefined in backend. here is the handleFile function: ` const handleFile = (ev) => {
    setFile(ev.target.files[0]);
    console.log(file);
  };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my route handler to this:

```js
publicUsersRouter
  .route("/register")
  .post(upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
        publicUsersService(req,res)
  }
```

Comment: this is unrelated to your original question

Comment: @traynor but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `publicUsersService` middleware function: the multer handler is never called, because you define it with parenthesis/parenthesized expression, so it resolves to the single/last handler (see: [Javascript expression in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201118/javascript-expression-in-parentheses)).

You need to define it with square brackets/array, and list route handlers within, so that they can be called/chained, see: [Route handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers).

change:

```
module.exports.publicUsersService =
    (
        upload.any(),
        (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.files);
            console.log(req.body);
        }
    )
```

to this:

```
module.exports.publicUsersService =
    [
        upload.any(),
        (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.files);
            console.log(req.body);
        }
    ]
```